# Flutter CachedNetworkImage - How to find time of cache

Tags: flutter, caching

I am using following script to cache network images in flutter app

```
String networkImageUrl = https://mysite/path/to/image.jpeg
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: networkImageUrl,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
)
```

**networkImageUrl** image can be replaced on server as a part of editing / up gradation of product. And the same is reflected at last-Modified part of header. After it changes I want to delete cache in front end and update the cached image.

My question is how do I know time of CachedNetworkImage, so that it can be compared with last-Modified header and I can delete cached image using following.

```
await CachedNetworkImage.evictFromCache(networkImageUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cacheKey property for CachedNetworkImage component; Once the cacheKey is changed, the image in cache will be replaced with new one

Comment: It worked, I added cacheKey:'$(networkImageUrl)-$(modificationTime)'